# Laravel 5.1 - Ajax call Error 500 (for only one function)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.1

I have a weird problem which I can't find a solution for.

**Ajax code:**

```
$("#details-comment-btn").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var functionType = "comment";
    var articleid=$('input[name=articleId]').val();
    var owner_id=$('input[name=owner_id]').val();
    var first_name=$('input[name=owner_first_name]').val();
    var last_name=$('input[name=owner_last_name]').val();
    var token=$('input[name=_token]').val();
    var commentBody = $('textarea[name=commentBody]').val();
    console.log(articleid);

    $.ajaxSetup({headers : {'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}});

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:articleid,
        data:
        {
            'user_id': owner_id,
            'commentBody': commentBody,
            'functionType': functionType,
            'article_id': articleid,
            '_token': token
        },
        success: function(){
            console.log(articleid);
            $('#newcomment').append('<div class="comment" id="newCommentDiv">');
                $('#newCommentDiv')
                        .append('<a href="/user/'+ owner_id +'/' + first_name + '/' + last_name + '" class="user">' + first_name + " " + last_name + '</a>')
                        .append('<span class="date">Just Now</span>')
                        .append('<p class="body">'+ commentBody + '</p>');
            $('#newcomment').fadeIn();
        }
    });
});
```

However, I always get the same error

> POST http://project.dev/articles/1 500 (Internal Server Error)

Here's the route I have for the post

```
Route::post('articles/{id}', 'DeleteController@deleteWork');
```

The link it show is fine, so I'm not sure why it's giving me the error.

The weird part is that other ajax calls who need to same URL work without any problems.

**For example, here's the code from another AJAX call which does work and uses the same "url".**

```
$('.articleFavo').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var userid= $('input[name=userID]' ).val();
    var functionType = 'favorite';
    var articleid=$('input[name=articleId]').val();
    var token=$('input[name=_token]').val();

    $.ajaxSetup({headers : {'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}});

    $.ajax({
        url:articleid,
        type: "post",
        data:
        {
            'functionType': functionType,
            'user_id': userid,
            'article_id': articleid,
            '_token': token
        },
        success: function(){
            console.log(articleid);
            $('#favoriteBtn'+ articleid).css({display: 'none'})
            $('#unfavoriteBtn'+ articleid).fadeIn();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What does DeleteController@deleteWork look like?

Comment: Have you checked in your logs?

Comment: @ChrisForrence http://pastebin.com/7zWjxjzR here's the controller

Comment: Show the error Laravel gives to you by clicking the error in your console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 378 in your controller, you have the following line:

```
$article_id = input::get('articleId');
```

However, you're sending up "article_id" in your AJAX call. It'll probably be better to update this line in the controller (to be consistent with the rest of your code)

```
$article_id = input::get('article_id');
```

Comment: As another suggestion, it looks like you're overloading that controller method _way_ too much; I'd highly advise splitting it out into multiple methods and putting them into pertinent controllers (for instance, inserting data via a DeleteController doesn't make much sense)